# Allow any user to view my freebusy on google calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

All I want to do is have my website be able to get free/busy status from one of my personal google calendars, which is shared publicly. It will then be able to display that info on the website without the user needing to log in or anything.

I fount this [help article](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php) but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can do this (But i think the first one is what you need)

1) Using Goolgle calendar API, you need to use the the "[freeBusy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query)" api, manipulate the JSON response and display it on your screen. This api doesn't need user authentication. You just need to provide the id, timeMin and timeMax to get the publicly shared calendar.

Sample request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "<YOUR-ID>"
  }
 ],
 "timeMin": "2015-12-24T00:00:00+10:00",
 "timeMax": "2015-12-31T00:00:00+10:00"
}
```

Sample Response:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
 "timeMin": "2015-12-23T14:00:00.000Z",
 "timeMax": "2015-12-30T14:00:00.000Z",
 "calendars": {
  "<YOUR-ID>": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2015-12-28T18:00:00Z",
     "end": "2015-12-28T18:25:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2015-12-30T09:00:00Z",
     "end": "2015-12-30T10:00:00Z"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

2) If you just want to show your calendar, You can directly embed your calendar by using the iframe code provided in your calendar settings. Here is the link for the [Detailed step by step instruction](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)

Comment: Ok, so the API Key and ID is something I get from google though right? Does that have something to do with OAuth 2.0? Is [this link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490) something I should be reading?

Comment: the API key is the one that you create in the developers console for your application (you can create that using that link) . And the ID is your calendar id usually it is your email but you can verify in your calendar settings. you can follow this link -- http://wpdocs.philderksen.com/google-calendar-events/getting-started/find-calendar-id/

Comment: OAuth is only required if you are going to use APIs which needs user authentication. Usually it is used to get user's private data.